# Texture looks fine in Texture Paint panel but distorted everywhere else

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I'm not sure how else to explain it, so here are pics. First, here's how it looks in the Texture Paint panel:

[image: a wooden table with well-aligned textures in the Texture Paint panel]

And now here's how it looks in the UV Editing panel without me changing anything:

[image: In the UV Editing panel, only a portion of the top face of the table shows the texture]

The top face of the table is selected in the UV Editing panel screenshot, so you can see that it corresponds to a square area of the UV map image fully filled in with tabletop texture--and yet, that same texture appears only in a corner of the actual tabletop model.

Any idea what the deal is with this? Is there some step to "bake" a texture paint that I'm missing or something?

Here's the blend file: [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your *Image Texture* you've chosen the *Box* option instead of *Flat*, this option will project the image onto the object perpendicularly to the 3 axis (it needs the *Generated* output of the *Texture Coordinate* to work properly), but it seems like in *Solid* mode the image will still be projected as *Flat* (not sure exactly the reason why, the *Solid* mode has its own display system):

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't it. There is only one UV map (named "UVMap") in the object data.

Comment: it may have to do with your node setup, please pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering how to do that! I've uploaded the blend file.

Comment: you need to share the link  ;)

Comment: Ha ha, oops.  I've edited the OP

Comment: ok I've edited, please check my answer

Comment: That did it--thanks so much! :)